# Sound on Dell XPS 9570 only works on headphones

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I have a Dell XPS 15 9570 and it's great, except that no sound comes out of the speakers. Weirdly enough it works just fine out of headphones! Just the built-in speakers are the problem.

Everything I can find reports all systems go. `pavucontrol` looks great:

[image: All my apps report working sound in pavucontrol]

[image: The Output Devices panel in pavucontrol also shows sound working]

`pactl list sinks` doesn't show anything that stands out to me:

```
Sink #0
State: RUNNING
Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
Driver: module-alsa-card.c
Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Owner Module: 6
Mute: no
Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        balance 0.00
Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
Latency: 22200 usec, configured 25000 usec
Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
Properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = "ALC3266 Analog"
    alsa.id = "ALC3266 Analog"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "0"
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xed618000 irq 146"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "a348"
    device.product.name = "Cannon Lake PCH cAVS"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "front:0"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
    device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
    alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC3266"
    alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0298,1028087c,00100103 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
Ports:
    analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000)
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, not available)
Active Port: analog-output-speaker
Formats:
    pcm
```

I also looked into a theory that the headphone jack wasn't registering plugs/unplugs, but as far as I can tell that's working just fine.

Anyway, I'm at a loss. Any ideas? I'm using Arch linux,and I'm using pulseaudio.

Comment: This is the output of `alsa-info.sh`: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=8587406fb1d95ece39dfe600547f55ff0b9dccdd

Comment: These are some outputs from amixer: https://gist.github.com/jfhbrook/386e0a0da6cb820a5495543f88cc4b74

Comment: I've made some progress here - it seems that pulseaudio is just fine, and it's likely that the issue is with the sound kernel module. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.20/sound/hd-audio/models.html this lists a bunch of codecs that the hd-audio module can be configured to use manually.

After a bunch of finagling I was able to get Dell's drivers page (behind an account wall but easy to dump garbage data into) that the sound hardware is supposed to be a "Realtek ALC3266". While the hd-audio codecs include stuff in that family, it doesn't include this card specifically. 

Comment: This is also significantly more google-able than "dell xps 15 no sound": https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=alc3266%20linux

Comment: It also seems that the hardware is the same as with the "dummy output" issue for other XPS 15s: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468071/no-sound-dummy-output-on-debian-9-fresh-install i guess the driver wasn't properly fixed after all?

See also: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109841

Answer (score 0):

So I *think* I have the closest thing this ticket can get to an answer, minus kernel upstream patches.

Sound on linux for sufficiently new machines operates through a kernel module called hd-audio. hd-audio uses various codecs to figure out how to actually play sound, which are listed here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.20/sound/hd-audio/models.html The takeaway here is that bugs/issues with hd-audio tend to either be detection issues, actual bugs in the appropriate codec, or some combination thereof.

I did some research to figure out what device the Dell XPS 15 9570 has, and by going to Dell's drivers page I was able to find that it's an ALC3266 - which is listed in the information in `pactl list sinks` actually.

This leads to the important insight that this card has had slightly different issues in the past: Specifically, the 9550 and the 9570 would have an issue where the sound would stop working completely when headphones were plugged in and the sound card would report "dummy output" on reboot [(link on stackexchange)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468071/no-sound-dummy-output-on-debian-9-fresh-install).

If you look closely at this issue, there are two things worth noting:

1. One particular issue, probably the "dummy output" issue, was reportedly fixed in November, as can be seen in the stackexchange link as well as [the patch linked therein](http://ubuntu.5.x6.nabble.com/SRU-Artful-OEM-PATCH-hda-driver-initialization-takes-too-much-time-on-the-machine-with-coffeelake-au-td5165811.html).
2. [The kernel ticket](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109841) is still open.

This leads me to the conclusion that the driver is still buggy, and that all I can really do (besides learning how to be a kernel hacker) is add my two cents to the issue and sit tight.